# How to keep fsi.exe open after running

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-scripting

I have a bunch of F# scripts (fsx) that I use for my basic deployment needs. I just right click them and say "Run with F# interactive"

However, sometimes the script fails and I would like to keep the interactive console running. So far I haven't figured out a nice way to achieve that.

I tried starting up the fsi.exe manually but then how can I launch my script from there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are hackish enough, you may want adding just another Explorer context menu item similar to `Run with F# Interactive`, but keeping the console window open after `.fsx` script terminates. Here is the working outline of how to achieve this for Windows7/VS2012:

- being admin open `regedit` and find the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.fsx.11.0\shell`
- add new subkey with some unique name, like `openRunCmd`, make `(Default)` value for this key whatever you like to see in context menu, maybe `Run with Fsi in shell`
- finally, add subkey `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.fsx.11.0\shell\openRunCmd\command` and set `(Default)` value for this subkey to the following line:

  `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /Q /K %%USERPROFILE%%\fsx.bat "%1"`

Now, close `regedit`, go to your home directory and create there a batch file `fsx.bat` with the following line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Fsi.exe" --quiet --exec "%1"
```

After these mods you would be able to click on any `.fsx` script with right mouse button, pick `Run with Fsi in shell` and have the shell window staying after script termination until you close it. With few small adjustments the same approach would work for VS2010.

Just be careful to adjust details, if your system settings differ from ones above. Good luck!

**Update**: For those who want to try this at home or at work I've posted a detailed walk-through [here](http://infsharpmajor.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/running-f-interactive-from-windows-context-menu/).

Comment: Wow! This sounds totally awesome. Will have to try it out as soon as possible (probably on monday though)

Comment: I've added a link to my answer with a detailed walk-through.

Comment: Thank you for your effort you put into this. I would double upvote if I could :)

Comment: thanks ! works with VS2013 and F# 3.1 (I just replace VisualStudio.fsx.11.0 -> 12.0 and ...\F#\3.0\... with ...\F#\3.1...)

Comment: @GeneBelitski can you confirm that this doesn't work if there's spaces in the path of the fsx, and that the correct fsx.bat is : `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Fsi.exe" --quiet --exec %1` (without quotes around %1) ?

Comment: I only have VS 2017 (Enterprise) installed and I can't find VisualStudio or .fsx anywhere under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.  Has the method of doing this changed?  Do I need to install an older version to accomplish this now?

Comment: @bielawski VS2015 seems the highest version that exposes the registry key `...\VisualStudio.fsx.14.0\shell\openRunFsi`. Given the loosening of ties between VS and F# ecosystem I'd settle upon a run method that does not rely on VS context.

Answer (score 3):

```
#load "myScipt.fsx";;
```

should work I think. But myself i prefer just to have separate console window (cmd.exe), from which i can run `fsi myScipt.fsx` and see the output.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a windows shortcut with

Target:

```
cmd /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\Fsi.exe" deploy.fsx
```

Start in:

```
C:\FolderContaningFsxScript
```

This keeps the window open if the script fails so I can see any compile errors. It also keeps the window open if the script runs successfully which might or might not be desirable.

I find it easier to just click the shortcut instead of Right Click > Run with F# Interactive. I think a batch file with the above command would work as well.